# I want link (on post and page) to be auto clicked when some visitor loads it

Tags: java, php

I have some external link on my blog posts and search result page.

I am interested in that, when someone load that page and post link should be auto clicked either in same windows or with `target="_blank"`.

Please, update me soon. I am so worried and searched on google but, nothing found working.

Comment: Simple: redirect to the new link when page loads.

Answer (score 3):

A simple redirect should be ok:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    location.href = "http://www.example.com";
});
```

I'm not really sure why would you need to imitate a browser click. If you do it for SEO purposes, I think it would be considered as blackhat. If there is any other purpose, I'm almost sure that you have poor architecture in your app, first of all.

Comment: Bro this is just for education purpose, because i am a teacher but still in learning phase.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it via javascript. if you are using jQuery library then you can do it as follows

Lets say you have a link defined like this , i just added a ID attribute.

```
<a id="sendbutton" href="myurl.com/data1&data2">CLICK</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#sendbutton')[0].click();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: <center>
<a id="sendbutton" href="http://myurl.com/abcdefgh=<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Screenshot_1_opt.jpg"</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#sendbutton')[0].click();
   });
</script>
</center>                                                                                                       or Please have a look at this screenshot that i tried if it is right or  wrong http://prntscr.com/9ciuo1

Comment: <center>
<a id="sendbutton" href="http://myurl.com/abcdefgh=<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Screenshot_1_opt.jpg"</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#sendbutton')[0].click();
   });
</script>
</center>                                                                                                       or Please have a look at this screenshot that i tried if it is right or  wrong http://prntscr.com/9ciuo1
@Abhishek and Pulkit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ready` function of `jQuery` which will fire any function on complete page load.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  window.open("https://google.com","_self");
});
</script>
```

P.S. _`self` will open the page in current window. For more options see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Dear experts
Abhishek B and Pulkit in which wp php file i should add these codes?

Comment: Page A which is loaded by the user(after which you will open the page B auto click)

Answer (score -1):

Hello i found answer there is simple thing to place any page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://www.example.com/" />
```